# How to write result of structured query with hive format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to insert into a hive table data via `DataStreamWriter` class using `hive` format.

```
  rdf.writeStream.format("hive").partitionBy("date")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/")
    .option("db", "default")
    .option("table", "Daily_summary_data")
    .queryName("socket-hive-streaming")
    .start()
```

It throws the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive data source can only be
>   used with tables, you can not write files of Hive data source
>   directly.;

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to write the result of a structured query using `hive` data source (as per the exception that you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.scala#L245-L247)).

You can write using `parquet` format that may be an option.

Comment: thanks for your help @Jacek Laskowski , I have already read your gitbook of spark sir, I was looking out for any way i can handle exception and write to hive table.

Comment: Write to parquet files, create a Hive table out of them and `REFRESH` every save. That should work (but haven't tried it out myself -- want to be the first?).